# rsync SERVER fails

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I have set up a rsync server -> /etc/rsyncd.conf

```
max connection = 5  
log file = /var/log/rsync.log  
[web]  
path = /srv/www/html  
read only = false  
list = yes  
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1  
uid = nobody  
gid = nobody  

[root@localhost www]# ls -l /srv/www/html/  
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 amit amit 8 Apr 28 10:37 index.html
```

If I do

```
$rsync 127.0.0.1::
$web
```

then it correctly shows the module name
but if I do

```
$rsync 127.0.0.1::web  
@ERROR: chroot failed  
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

I dont know why? I am testing working of rsync first on localhost as it failed rsync remotely.

Comment: In my case I received this error when the target directory didn't yet exist.

Answer (score 21):

The solution is
In /etc/rsyncd.conf on server add

```
use chroot = false
```

I have no clue why its true by default. Got to the solution by luck while browsing rsync documentation. Hope this saves time for others.
Cheers

Comment: According to the documentation, this solution has some security consequences. In my case, I'm good with those consequences. But please check the manpage, as to how it relates to you.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and noticed the path I was giving in the `rsyncd.conf` at the server end was wrong.
Actual path was
`path=/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/folder`
but I was giving
`path=/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/folder`
when I corrected the path is worked. So ensure that your path is correct, has right ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an SELinux issue, it needs to know that the folder can be used by the rsync daemon. Let's consider an example, to rsync the following folder: `/home/myuser/ftp`

The following commands need to be run to set the correct SELinux context:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t rsync_data_t '/home/myuser(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv '/home/myuser'
setsebool -P rsync_client on
```

Strangely enough, I noticed the parent folder must be labelled, hence why the labelling is done on `/home/myuser` instead of `/home/myuser/ftp`. Restricting to the `ftp` subfolder is simply done in the rsync daemon configuration.

You can check the SELinux labelling by running:

```
ls -Z /home/myuser
```

An interesting article about why combining chroot and SELinux is a good idea: http://blog.siphos.be/2012/04/why-both-chroot-and-selinux/